# How do I show a spinning GIF while main form is working

Tags: vb.net, gif, ui-thread

I'm working on a Windows forms application written with VB.NET, and i like to show a spining wheel(GIF) while the app is working without the UI frozes and without any delay showing the GIF, but the gif is not showing until all the work is finished.

In my form i have a Button that starts all the work.

```
Public Class Form1
Private _pb As PictureBox

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t As New Task(AddressOf ShowSpinningGif)
    t.Start()

    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim b As Integer = 999999999
    For i As Integer = 0 To b
        a += 1
    Next

    Dim t1 As New Task(AddressOf EndSpinningGif)
    t1.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub ShowSpinningGif()
    Dim pb As New PictureBox
    With pb
        .Image = My.Resources.b
        .BringToFront()
        .Show()
    End With
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub()
                      Me.Controls.Add(pb)
                  End Sub)
    Else
        Me.Controls.Add(pb)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub EndSpinningGif()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub()
                      _pb.Dispose()
                  End Sub)
    Else
        _pb.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
End Sub

End Class
```

I've tryed using the Thread and BackgroundWorker class and all the same.

I don't mind to change the GIF or use a UserControl that contains a painted weel or something like that, but i've like to avoid changing the mouse pointer or using a ProgressBar.

I know that the loop is freezing the UI thread, but i was hoping that putting the image on another thread the GIF continue spinning while all the work is done.

I know that if i put the loop in a thread all works, but i also was hoping to avoid that because i doesn't like much to create and start a thread every time that my app has to do heavy work.

Anyone have an idea to accomplish this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` <- This is the first indicator showing that you're doing something wrong. That property should never be changed, and will only ever work in Debug mode anyway (not in the standalone application).

Comment: Your `For i As Integer = 0 To b` loop is executed on the UI thread, which is why everything freezes. It is that part that should be put in a thread, not the displaying of an image. Only the heavy code should be put in threads, not UI-updating code.

Comment: Hi Visual Vincent, thank you for your help

Comment: I know that the loop is freezing the UI thread, but i was hoping that putting the image on another thread the GIF continue spinning while all the work is done.
I know that if i put the loop in a thread all works, but i also was hoping to avoid that because i doesn't like much to create and start a thread every time that my app has to do heavy work.

Do you know any kind of solution for this? 
Thank you again.

Comment: Well you'll just have to get used to it, because **the only** solution is to put the heavy work in another thread. You cannot put the animation in another thread because **A)** You cannot perform cross-thread operations to the UI thread, and **B)** The painting is done by the UI thread **only**, and if it's constantly busy then it doesn't have time to repaint. The UI thread has a message loop which controls all interactions and updating of the UI. If that loop cannot run because another one takes over then it will freeze.

Comment: If you think it's too annoying creating new methods for your threads, use [**Lambda Expressions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) instead just like you do when you call `Me.Invoke`.

Comment: Thanks alot Visual Vincent.:)

Comment: No problem. Good luck!